# $A$ and $x$ are known and $B$ is unknown and also we have $Ax=0$ and $ABx=0$. How can we find $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that A is a matrix and x is a column vector and both of them are known.  Suppose that B is an unknown diagonal square matrix and the following equations hold
$$ Ax=0 $$
and
$$ ABx=0 $$

The solution of B is a vector space because if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are two solutions, $\alpha B_1 + \beta B_2$ is also a solution where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars.

How can we find a basis for B?

Obviously one of the solutions of B is $\alpha I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Obviously if $A$ is full column rank then the only possible $x$ is zero vector and $B$ can be any matrix. But what if $A$ is not full column rank and $x$ is not a zero vector?

Is there any closed form solution to obtain a basis for B?

Comment: Write $B=diag(b)$, then you could use $Bx=diag(x)b$ to obtain a standard linear system of equations.

Comment: @AndreasLenz Yes definitely we can do that. But in this way the property that $Ax=0$ is not used. I am interested to see if the fact that  $Ax=0$ makes the answer of $ABx=0$ more restricted. For example, if we could show that if A is not full column rank but is full row rank then only possibly $B$ is $\alpha I$ then it would be a useful property.

Answer (score 1):

Some preliminaries: $Ax = 0$ means $x \in ker A$, and $ABx = 0$ means $Bx \in \ker A$. Also, suppose that the ground field is $K$, and $x \in K^n$.

We can find a basis of $\ker A$ such that $x$ is one of the basis vectors (pick a basis, and swap in $x$ using the exchange lemma). Suppose $\dim \ker A = k$; we know that $\ker A \cong K^k$, and can therefore find a base change matrix $T$ such that $Ty \in K^k \oplus 0^{n-k}$ (i.e., $T$ induces an isomorphism $\ker A \cong K^k \oplus \{ 0 \}^{n-k} \subseteq K^k \oplus K^{n-k}$). We can arrange for this base change to have $Tx = e_1$, the first unit vector.

Let $A' := AT^{-1}$ and $x' := Tx$; obviously, $A'B'x' = 0$ iff $A(TB'T^{-1})x = 0$. This allows us to reduce to the case where $\ker A' = K^k \oplus \{ 0 \}^{n-k}$ and $x' = e\_1$ -- find $B'$ for this setting and set $B := TB'T^{-1}$. Therefore, without loss of generality, we may assume $x = e_1$ and $\ker A = K^k \oplus \{ 0 \}$.

But in this case, finding all $B$ is straightforward: all that is required is that $ABe_1 = 0$, or equivalentely, the first column of $B$ must be in $\ker A$. This is the case if and only if $B_{1,j} = 0$ for all $j$ with $k < j \le n$. Thus, a basis for the $B$ can be given by the matrices $E_{i,j}$ with $i \le k$ or $j > 1$, where $E_{i,j}$ has exactly one 1 at position $i,j$ and is 0 everywhere else.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $\ker A \cong K^k$ and also $Ty \in K^k \oplus 0^{n-k}$. By $\ker A \cong K^k$, do you mean that  $\ker A$ is a subspace of $K^n$ with a dimension of $k$? Could you please explain the notation $K^k \oplus 0^{n-k}$ and $\ker A = K^k \oplus \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: Any link that helps me become familiar with these notations would be appreciated.

Comment: @alireza Sorry, I thought you might know this. $\ker A \cong K^k$ means that $\ker A$ and $K^k$ are isomorphic, i.e., there is an invertible linear map from $\ker A$ to $K^k$ - so yes, you can read this as "$\ker A$ is a subspace of $K^n$ with dimension $k$".

Comment: By $K^k \oplus 0^{n-k}$, I was trying to describe the subspace of $K^n$ where the first $k$ components of each vector are arbitrary, and the others are all 0: for vector spaces $V, W$, $V \oplus W$ describes the vector space consisting of pairs $(v, w)$, $v \in V$, w \in W$ (so, basically, "concatenated vectors").

Comment: By that token, $\ker A = K^k \oplus \{ 0 \}^{n-k}$ means "$\ker A$ consists of vectors where the first $k$ components are arbitrary, and the rest is 0".

Comment: Thanks. Another issues is that if A is full column rank (k=0), then B can be any arbitrary matrix. But according to your last paragraph, $B_{1,j}$ should be equal to zero for $k=0<j \le n$. Also in terms of $E_{i,j}$ that you described, there is no positive $i$ such that $i \le k=0$. So it seems that there is something wrong here. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, but that's no problem: it just means rhere are constraints, ao any $B$ will do.